# Java null layout & Revalidate

Tags: java, swing

We are making a little game for school, but my group is running into some trouble. We've build our application using a Null layout manager and placing every element on an absolute position. Now we are running into some problems we can't fix on our own.

As soon as we start the application it looks fine, but as well call Minimize the application and restore it all our elements have - what it looks like - their positions removed. This also happens when we call removeAll() followed by Revalidate().

I've lined some screenshots to clarify what I'm talking about. Is there anyone out here who can help us with this?

App working fine on startup: http://s8.postimg.org/erobuux51/app_startup.jpg

App failing after a minimize: http://s30.postimg.org/nc4tosaup/app_failed.jpg

Comment: simply don't use null layout. Use a proper layout manager. start from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Using revalidate() won't help. The revalidate() method invokes the layout managers to set the size/location of all the components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code, all I can do is point you to Oracle's Swing [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Maybe Oracle can help you.  Spend a good bit of time (months) studying the tutorial.

Based on your comment.  You should **never** do a removeAll on a JPanel with Swing elements.  You should **almost never** do a removeAll on a JPanel with JPanels.  Here's Oracle's [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Maybe Oracle can help you.

Finally, here's an article I wrote that shows you how to put everything Oracle explains together.  [Hangman Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=349).

Comment: Well there isn't much interesting code to show I guess. Its just we add JLabels and JButtons to a JPanel (thats on a JFrame), and as soon as we call RemoveAll and Revalidate on that JPanel or minimize our application the position is gone

Comment: @Thijs, please start with learning a layout manager. When you do one or more thing with them, you are going to love them. seriously

Comment: "You should never do a removeAll on a JPanel with Swing elements"? Is this there in Oracle's documentation?

Comment: What is the solution? I have to keep a my own list of components and remove them one by one?

Answer (score -1):

null layout maybe hated by most Java Swing developers, but it shouldn't be the cause of the failure of your program. Simply use null layout + minimize of the frame should not cause the components to relocate. I think there must be some other mistakes you have made that caused this problem.